# Creating a keystore from private key and a public key

Tags: java, keystore, pem

I have java code that needs a keystore and I have privateKey.pem and bank.cer file. Private key would be to sign a value to bank and bank.cer to verify banks response. I can't find a way to put them into a keystore so my code would work.

Can it be done with keytool?

Comment: I think it would be good if you could provide what you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried importing with keytool but it imports as trustedCertEntry but I would like it to be a privateKeyEntry. Also tried a java program called ktl241 that said java.lang.Exception: obj: not an instance of X509Certificate when importing private key pem. Also tried the top search results from google.

Comment: I once wrote a blog entry on how to do that. Maybe it helps: http://quakology.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-ssl-with-client-certificate.html

Comment: Thank you for answering but it didn't work. Got No certificate matches private key.
My pem contain only private key

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store?

Comment: It did put the private key in the keystore. Is it ok though? Because the private key and cert I had are not a pair but are now in keystore as a pair.

Comment: I think this should be right. I'm facing similar problems right now but I think I found another solution. I'll answer with that and we'll see if it works for you too.

Answer (score 20):

From my understanding it's impossible to do this with `keytool` alone. I use `openssl` for preparation.

Suppose the key is in file `key` and the certificate is in a file `cert`. You have to create a PKCS12 file that contains both (because `keytool` can handle PKCS12 and JKS and I don't know if anything else):

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey key -in cert -export -out keys.pkcs12
```

Now you can import that into a keystore:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keys.pkcs12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore mykeystore
```

This approach worked for me where everything else failed.

Comment: To list the whole chain in the keystore's private-key-entry, you can cat together several .pem files of the certificate chain, and add them to the pkcs-store using openssl's `-certfile` option.

Comment: This worked for me. However, I had to make sure to always use the same password; I thought I could write and read the PKCS12 with a temporary password, and only give the *real* one for the output of `keytool`, but that created a keystore where keystore and key had different passwords, which apparently is very bad (http://joewlarson.com/blog/2009/03/25/java-ssl-use-the-same-password-for-keystore-and-key/).

Comment: @musiKk's solution worked for me with a minor change while creating the PKCS12 file, set the password, otherwise there will be an error for the later keytool command. openssl pkcs12 -inkey key -in cert -export -out keys.pkcs12 -passout pass:yourpasswd

Comment: I have an intermediate certificate and a root certificate, please which one should I use?