# SSL convert url to .crt

Tags: ssl, openssl, keystore

How can I convert this url to a .crt file?
https://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt?raw=1

Please do not say perl. I have openssl & jvakeyUtil Ultimately want to create a trustStore.jks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html has probably what you want. It contains the data already converted in the format you want. If you really want to convert the data yourself look at the source code of the mk-ca-bundle perl program which they used to create the converted data.

Comment: Hi Steffen, can I just grab this link HTTP from curl.haxx.se: cacert.pem http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
and save it as a .crt or should then use javaKeyUtil to insert the certificate in my trustStore.jks? Please spell all steps out.

Comment: @GeorgeMurphy: how about doing a bit of the work yourself. A quick search turns up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store

Comment: Steffen Ullrich you assume wrong. I have  been working on this for quite some time. Can do without the totally unhelpful false comments.

Comment: @GeorgeMurphy: sorry, but "please spell all steps out" does not show any efforts from your site. It would be better to show what you've tried. See also http://stackoverflow.com/about: "..Include details about what you have tried..."