# Consuming a SAML 2.0 assertion with ColdFusion - What do I do with a public key (.pem) file?

Tags: coldfusion, x509certificate, saml, cfml, pem

I am tasked with getting our ColdFusion 9 app to receive a SAML assertion for single sign-on.  We are the service provider.  Thus far, I have used the only real source of information about ColdFusion and SAML at the following URL for guidance: http://blog.tagworldwide.com/?p=19

I have a sample SAML XML assertion from the identity provider and it looks very similar to the following example from Salesforce.com.

```
<samlp:Response ID="_257f9d9e9fa14962c0803903a6ccad931245264310738" 
   IssueInstant="2009-06-17T18:45:10.738Z" Version="2.0">
<saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">
   https://www.salesforce.com
</saml:Issuer>

<samlp:Status>
   <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
</samlp:Status>

<saml:Assertion ID="_3c39bc0fe7b13769cab2f6f45eba801b1245264310738" 
   IssueInstant="2009-06-17T18:45:10.738Z" Version="2.0">
   <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">
      https://www.salesforce.com
   </saml:Issuer>

   <saml:Signature>
      <saml:SignedInfo>
         <saml:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
         <saml:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
         <saml:Reference URI="#_3c39bc0fe7b13769cab2f6f45eba801b1245264310738">
            <saml:Transforms>
               <saml:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
               <saml:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                  <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ds saml xs"/>
               </saml:Transform>
            </saml:Transforms>
            <saml:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <saml:DigestValue>vzR9Hfp8d16576tEDeq/zhpmLoo=
            </saml:DigestValue>
         </saml:Reference>
      </saml:SignedInfo>
      <saml:SignatureValue>
         AzID5hhJeJlG2llUDvZswNUrlrPtR7S37QYH2W+Un1n8c6kTC
         Xr/lihEKPcA2PZt86eBntFBVDWTRlh/W3yUgGOqQBJMFOVbhK
         M/CbLHbBUVT5TcxIqvsNvIFdjIGNkf1W0SBqRKZOJ6tzxCcLo
         9dXqAyAUkqDpX5+AyltwrdCPNmncUM4dtRPjI05CL1rRaGeyX
         3kkqOL8p0vjm0fazU5tCAJLbYuYgU1LivPSahWNcpvRSlCI4e
         Pn2oiVDyrcc4et12inPMTc2lGIWWWWJyHOPSiXRSkEAIwQVjf
         Qm5cpli44Pv8FCrdGWpEE0yXsPBvDkM9jIzwCYGG2fKaLBag==
      </saml:SignatureValue>
      <saml:KeyInfo>
         <saml:X509Data>
            <saml:X509Certificate>
               MIIEATCCAumgAwIBAgIBBTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0FADCBgzELM
               [Certificate truncated for readability...]
            </saml:X509Certificate>
         </saml:X509Data>
      </saml:KeyInfo>
   </saml:Signature>

   <saml:Subject>
      <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">
         saml01@salesforce.com
      </saml:NameID>

      <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
      <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2009-06-17T18:50:10.738Z" 
         Recipient="https://login.www.salesforce.com"/>
      </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
   </saml:Subject>

   <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2009-06-17T18:45:10.738Z" 
      NotOnOrAfter="2009-06-17T18:50:10.738Z">

      <saml:AudienceRestriction>
         <saml:Audience>https://saml.salesforce.com</saml:Audience>
      </saml:AudienceRestriction>
   </saml:Conditions>

   <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2009-06-17T18:45:10.738Z">
      <saml:AuthnContext>
         <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified
         </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
      </saml:AuthnContext>
   </saml:AuthnStatement>

   <saml:AttributeStatement>

      <saml:Attribute Name="portal_id">
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">060D00000000SHZ
         </saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>

      <saml:Attribute Name="organization_id">
         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">00DD0000000F7L5
         </saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>

      <saml:Attribute Name="ssostartpage" 
         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">

         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">
            http://www.salesforce.com/security/saml/saml20-gen.jsp
         </saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>

      <saml:Attribute Name="logouturl" 
         NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">

         <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">
            http://www.salesforce.com/security/del_auth/SsoLogoutPage.html
         </saml:AttributeValue>
      </saml:Attribute>
   </saml:AttributeStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

The Identify Provider also gave us a `.pem` file that apparently contains two certificate blocks.  I don't know what I am supposed to do with this file.  If I pull out the X509Certificate block in the assertion and decode it using a website like http://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html, I can see the info it contains.

I have example code running so far that tests whether or not the XML signature and cert is valid.  It currently is not.  However, nothing in the code refers to the `.pem` file.

So what am I supposed to do with the *.pem file that has been provided?  Any hints?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, I am continuing to try to solve my own problem.  As I mentioned, the `.pem` file I have contains 2 cert blocks, so I decoded them to see the contents.  The first one contains info about the Identity Provider.  The second contains info about DigiCert Inc.

I am beginning to think that the purpose of the IDP cert in the `.pem` file is simply to match against the one sent within the XML assertion itself as a primary security check.  Is that right?

Comment: I would assume that you need to import the certificates to the Java keystore on your server **_if_** you are connecting to their service via https (using cfhttp in ColdFusion). http://stackoverflow.com/q/2138940/1636917

Comment: @Miguel-F Thanks for this.  They are simply posting the XML over to us via a form, so I'm not sure this applies, but it definitely has expanded my thinking.