# SSL/TLS - PEM to JKS

Tags: java, ssl, pem, jks

I generated my private key with openssl and it is file serverkey.pem, I have also serverreq.pem that I sent to cert authority. They will send me signed certificate.

Is there any way how to convert serverkey.pem into Java Key Store? Do I have to generate something else or does it need only private key serverkey.pem? Can I do it with Keytool?

I know how to import cacerts and the signed cert into existing JKS, but I don't know how to create JKS from private key PEM. Thanks for any help.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store) help you

Comment: Seems good, but I'm unable to convert my PEM into DER as @Brian Knoblauch, I don't know if my file is correct it sttarts with
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- and I'm getting error:
WARNING: can't open config file: c:/openssl-1.0.1i-win32/ssl/openssl.cnf
unable to load certificate
1068:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE