# import .pem file in jre using keytool [Windows 7]

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, digital-certificate

I have .pem file to access https url, but i am not able to import it in my local JDK, I am not sure which format should be accepted by keytool (.pem, .der, .cer, .jks, or .cer).

I found some solutions but that were using openssl,[Import PEM into Java Key Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store) but i have to use keytool,

And also, When i execute "keytool -list" command on CMD, its giving me exception keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist:

can anyone give me steps to import a .pem file in jre

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean, you want to import .pem file into JRE truststore? Truststore file is located in `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts`. Default password is "changeit".

Keytool accepts .pem certificate as well, so you don't need to convert it to another format. Simply execute the following import command,

```
keytool -import -alias <PROVIDE_UNIQUE_CERTIFICATE_ALIAS_HERE> -file <PATH_TO_PEM_FILE> -keystore <JRE_TRUSTSTORE_FILE> -storepass <TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD>
```

> And also, When i execute "keytool -list" command on CMD, its giving me
>   exception keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not
>   exist:

You need to specify the keystore path as well as the keystore password,

```
keytool -list -keystore <JRE_TRUSTSTORE_FILE> -storepass <TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD>
```

If you would like to know more about keytool commands, this following link could be your best buddy,

https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html