# Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters for import

Tags: keytool

I wanted to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/7094044/384674 for importing pem into p12, but keystore password is 5 characters and keytool is complaining it needs to be 6 :-/

```
keytool -import -alias alias -keystore ./trust.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -file new.pem
Enter keystore password:
Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
```

**edit:**

There was a comment, this is not working in some of later versions of keytool but comment was removed, please be aware or let us know as I do not know version I was testing with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I found is, that when you specify `-storepass` as a parameter, validation is not active.

Comment: With recent versions of Java this is not true anymore. With OpenJDK 11.0.6 the error is now also present when specifying the password on the command line.

Comment: I use OpenJDK 11.0.12 and was able to use -storepass successfully