# How to configure kafka for TLS communication using `PEM` encoded files in java

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

How to configure kafka for TLS communication using `PEM` encoded files in java client. All the documentation I see out there talks about creating and using java `KeyStore` and `trustStore`.

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html , https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/ , https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html

I have `x.509` encoded cert, private_key and ca files, how I use them to connect to kafka in golang (just an example) is something like this

```
func connect(brokers []string, certs map[string][]byte) {

    certpool := x509.NewCertPool()
    certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM(certs["ca"])
    c, err := tls.X509KeyPair(certs["cert"], certs["private_key"])

    tls := tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            certpool,
        ClientAuth:         tls.NoClientCert,
        ClientCAs:          nil,
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{c},
    }

    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Producer.Return.Successes = true
    config.Net.TLS.Enable = true
    config.Net.TLS.Config = &tls
}
```

How can I replicate the same behavior in java, maybe I am missing something here but is there any api/documentation that I can refer which lets us configure PEM encoded contents rather than creating `keyStore`?

Answer (score 3):

As of 2.7.0, Kafka supports the PEM format.

This is the merge request that implemented it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10338

This is the proposal for adding the PEM format which documents the feature better than their docs/security.html:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-651+-+Support+PEM+format+for+SSL+certificates+and+private+key

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `PEM` encoded secrets with Java directly.

Using `openssl` and `keytool` you can import your certificate into a JKS for your Java clients.

See [Import PEM into Java Key Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store)

Comment: I see, is there any particular reason why java does not have out of the box support for configuring TLS using PEM files ??

Comment: That, I'm afraid, I don't know!