# How to create keystore and truststore file from Amazon RDS root CA certificate to setup TCPS connection from java code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, keystore, pem, truststore

I want to connect to Oracle RDS of AWS using secured TCPS connection, I have followed "Setting Up an SSL Connection Over JDBC" of 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.html#Appendix.Oracle.Options.SSL.TLS document, as per the doc I need to add only truststore file, but as I am getting connection reset issue, so after went through couple of blog's I realised that I should have add both truststore and keystore file, so can anyone please help me to generate truststore and keystore file from https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2015-root.pem PEM file.

Comment: Possible duplicate see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store

Comment: @RodrigoM thanks for your reply...but in that link they have mentioned only truststore file, but I have to create both truststore and ketsyore files, please let me know if you have any solution for that.