# Certificate with extension der

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, der

How to import a .der certificate into the certificate store? The aplliance es OUD the Oracle.

I do not know how to add a certificate with DER extension to the certificate store, keystore

Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import PEM into Java Key Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store)

Comment: @luk2302 PEM is not DER

Comment: @Lothar read the answer and look at the code used there.

Comment: You can add many different key/certificate formats to a Java keystore by using keystore-explorer (https://keystore-explorer.org/).
I always prefer keystore-explorer over keytool.

Comment: @luk2302 Its just storage format - cert is the same.