# Jmeter ca and client side certificates

Tags: performance, ssl, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I have 4 .pem files out of which 1 is ca certificate, and the rest are client side certificates. I tried adding them on Jmeter GUI by selecting `Options->SSL Manager`.

But it lets me select one certificate only. Moreover, there's no option to disable SSL verification after adding certificate.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As per [SSL Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SSL_Manager) documentation

   > You may either use a **Java Key Store (JKS) format key store, or a Public Key Certificate Standard #12 (PKCS12)** file for your client certificates.

   so you won't be able to load certificates from .pem files this way
2. You can use SSL Manager only for GUI mode and a single client certificate, for multiple certificates and/or [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) you need to specify the keystore location and password via system.properties file and if needed use [Keystore Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) if you want to use different certificates for different users.

So you need to:

- [Put the certificates into a single .pem](https://success.trendmicro.com/solution/1106466-combining-root-certificate-authority-ca-and-intermediate-ca-into-one-file)
- Convert this .pem into Java Keystore using [OpenSSL](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html) or [keytool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store)
- Point JMeter to use this keystore via `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` property and specify the keystore password via `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword` property
- Enjoy encrypted requests from JMeter

More information: [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response. I followed your steps and was able to add those certs to jmeter.