# Make HTTPS GET request using http connector in Mule with SSL certificates

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, anypoint-platform

I have `.crt` and `privatekey.pem` keys which can be used for making `HTTPS` `GET` API request.

We can't use these certificates directly in mulesoft for making https API requests.

As far I know it supports `Trust store configuration` and `Key store configuration` in the `JCEKS`, `JKS` and `PKCS12` formats

I have tried using the command below

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.private.pem -out certificate.der
keytool -import -alias your-alias -keystore cacerts -file certificate.der
```

It's failing with the error below after running `openssl` command mentioned below

```
unable to load certificate
140706477451034:error:09A2F34C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/Library/BuildRoots/97f7341o-dq75-11ed-a4bc-863efbbaf86g/Library/Caches/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:694:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

how I can convert my keys to these specific formats and how I can use it while making https get requests from Mulesoft's Anypoint Studio

I didn't find a right article for converting .CRT and .PEM files to Mule supported file formats.

Comment: There are dozen of blogs and previous Stackoverflow answers explaining how to convert certificate formats. Search for how to convert or import those formats to a Java keystore or just PKCS12. By the way you said MuleSoft when you mean Mule runtime.

Comment: @aled can you point me to one right blog in which they showed converting .crt and .pem files to pkcs12 format and used it in mulesoft?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+import+pem+to+keystore. I'll leave the CRT search as an exercise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import PEM into Java Key Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138940/import-pem-into-java-key-store)

Comment: Let me give it a try and confirm

Comment: I'm trying openssl command to convert .pem to .der format. somehow it's not working. it's giving this error `unable to load certificates`. But I'm giving the right certificate path in openssl command

Comment: Then open a question with all the details, including command, versions, output.

Comment: I'm updating this question

Comment: The error happens after executing openssl or executing the keytool command?

Comment: After running openssl command. updated the entire error message in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253722/discussion-between-aled-and-dubru).

Comment: Sure, let me join the chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the two `.crt` and `privatekey.pem` files into a single `JKS` file, as required by the Mule HTTP connector for sending `HTTPS` `GET` requests with certificates

The commands to convert `.crt` and `privatekey.pem` certs into `JKS` files are listed below.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private_key.pem -in certificate.crt -out keystore.p12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

The `keystore.jks` file will be created and then placed in the mule's project `src/main/resource`  folder as seen in the picture below.

[image]

After adding it, click on `+` under Basic Settings to add a http connector and set a configuration similar to the one shown in the following picture.

[image]

Finally, provide the `GET` method and the `Path` as per your API and then deploy the Mule application. It's done.